# Boost converter for constant voltage

Tags: batteries, power-electronics, boost, voltage

I have 36V as my input and I want 36V as the output of the [boost](https://electrobes.com/product/400w-15a-step-up-boost-converter-constant-current-dc-dc-step-up-module/) converter. I just have a very simple question if anyone has used such modules? If the input is a battery and my voltage drained to 18V. Will the boost converter automatically adjust its output to 36V or do I have to change the knob of the potentiometer again and again.

Comment: Are you just wanting to use the regulator to maintain a fixed output voltage as the battery is discharged and its voltage sags?

Comment: The pot is used for setting the output voltage. The converter should automatically adjust what you have set with the pot.

Comment: From reading the description it seems you only need to adjust the potentiometer when setting your desired output. Provided your battery has enough capacity remaining and can provide the current required to maintain 36V at the output at 18V it should be fine.
It would be helpful if you included details about the battery you intend to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will adjust automatically, hence voltage *regulator*.

If you take a look under the hood, there is a feedback mechanism which measures the output voltage, compares with an (internal) voltage reference and adjust its duty cycle to maintain the output voltage.

Comment: So is this correct to say that as the input voltage decreases the output voltage decrease as well but due to the feedback it increases the duty cycle to maintain that output level?

Comment: @kam1212 Yes, until it reaches some point, peak current or maximum duty cycle, at which point output voltage will decrease and the converter is no longer in regulation.